# Can't build Node.js on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: gcc, node.js, segmentation-fault

When I try to build Node.js on my Ubuntu 10.04 server it fails with the following error:

```
/etc/node/deps/v8/src/hydrogen.cc: In member function 'v8::internal::HInstruction* v8::internal::HGraphBuilder::BuildBinaryOperation(v8::internal::BinaryOperation*, v8::internal::HValue*, v8::internal::HValue*)':
/etc/node/deps/v8/src/hydrogen.cc:4912: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

When building I ran the following commands:

```
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
mkdir ~/local
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
```

I also tried to compile it without setting --prefix and it worked. It didn't work to install it, though. Got this error when running make install:

```
Unable to install the file 'deps/uv/c-ares/ares_build.h' (not found in dir:///etc/node)
```

I have tried this with 0.4.8 and 0.4.0 but I get a segmentation fault on both of them.

Here is some more information:

- OS: Ubuntu 10.04
- Arch: x64
- Node versions: 0.4.8 or 0.4.0
- GCC version: 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

Any ideas?

Comment: Not nearly enough information. I've built mine with no problems. What walkthrough are you using as a template on how to build? Please give us more details that are pertinent to your situation.

Comment: I ran: git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/joyent/node.git && cd node && mkdir ~/local && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node && make - Tried to compile it without setting --prefix and it worked. It didn't work to install it, though. Got this error when running make install: Unable to install the file 'deps/uv/c-ares/ares_build.h' (not found in dir:///etc/node)

Comment: Why only `--depth 1` ? try removing that.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. (Why whould it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried install node.js myself. The problem is that by default the branch points at master which is unstable. Before installing it call

```
$ git checkout origin/v0.4
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ make install
```

Of course you also want to install `npm` after node because everyone loves it

`$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Comment: It actually worked. I am no git guru, but why didn't `git checkout v0.4.0` work? Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Because when you do `git clone` you only clone the master branch and not the rest. So you have no 0.4.0 branch. You have to load this branch from the remote source (origin) so that's why checking out `origin\v0.4.0` works.